# Power BI Report Server frequently getting error when loading report

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I often encounter an error while loading reports on Power BI Report Server. Although it sometimes resolves on its own, I have noticed that the following URL generates an error 500: `/powerbi/api/explore/reports/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx/modelsAndExploration`. I also added related logs in below.

I'm using version **May 2023**, I had same problem with previous versions but I could fix it by modifying some scripts on report servers' database, unfortunately now I can't find that solution in internet.

Can you please provide guidance on how to fix this error?
[image: error evidence]

```
2023-07-25 15:16:41.2911|INFO|59|Received request GET /api/explore/reports/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx/modelsAndExploration| RequestID = e56c0d34-6bf1-00e6-2982-d429a746d07d ClientSessionID = b2655a34-c9d1-8ac7-eac4-1174b1846876
2023-07-25 15:16:41.3067|ERROR|59|Unhandled error in the Web API|GET https://example.com/powerbi/api/explore/reports/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx/modelsAndExploration?p... - Response Unknown| RequestID = e56c0d34-6bf1-00e6-2982-d429a746d07d ClientSessionID = b2655a34-c9d1-8ac7-eac4-1174b1846876 System.IO.IOException: There is no data in the database for @CatalogItemId=e6e41eba-a41c-425d-a7d0-33a53a22e578;@ContentType=PowerBIReportDefinition
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.CatalogAccess.Streams.VarbinaryReadableStream.InitializeDatabaseAccess()
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.CatalogAccess.Streams.VarbinaryReadableStreamFactory.CreateExtendedContentReadableStream(Guid catalogItemId, ExtendedContentType contentType)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.CatalogAccess.CatalogItemAccessor.GetExtendedContentReadable(Guid catalogItemId, ExtendedContentType contentType)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ReportServer.WebApi.Catalog.CatalogService.<GetPowerBIReportDefinitionStream>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ReportServer.WebApi.Catalog.CatalogService.<GetPbixComponentsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.ReportServer.WebApi.PbiApi.PbiApiController.<GetModelsAndExplorationAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by following instruction in this article: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/There-is-no-data-in-the-database-for-catalogitemid/td-p/1716998

**ROOT CAUSE**

===========

Change to GetCatalogExtendedContentData stored procedure via fix in May 2020

ICM 179612428

User Story 324871: Incident 179612428 : CSS – PBIRS/PBIX Reports display a blank page when executed during the SaveToCatalog Step during Schedule/OnDemand Refresh (3/13)

**WORKAROUND**

=============

To revert back to the previous version of the GetCatalogExtendedContentData stored procedure, you can replace this:

```
SELECT 

        DATALENGTH([Content]) AS ContentLength, 

        [Content] 

    FROM 

        [CatalogItemExtendedContent] WITH (NOWAIT) -- DevNote: Using NOWAIT here because for large models the row might be locked for long durations. Fail fast and let the client retry. 

    WHERE 

        [ItemID] = @CatalogItemID AND ContentType = @ContentType
```

With this:

```
SELECT 

        DATALENGTH([Content]) AS ContentLength, 

        [Content] 

    FROM 

        --[CatalogItemExtendedContent] WITH (NOWAIT) -- DevNote: Using NOWAIT here because for large models the row might be locked for long durations. Fail fast and let the client retry. 

        [CatalogItemExtendedContent] WITH (READPAST) -- Pre-May 2020 code 

    WHERE 

        [ItemID] = @CatalogItemID AND ContentType = @ContentType
```